# PHP удалить первую строчку в файле

Tags: php

Мне нужно из PHP удалить первую строчку txt файла.
Загружать файл в переменную и массив можно, он небольшой.
И задача записать это обратно в файл тоже не стоит.
На выходе должна быть переменная с удалённой 1-ой строчкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$txt = file('ваш файл');  
unset($txt[0]);  
implode ...
```

Ну или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: а что после implode? нужна переменная на выходе

Comment: После implode и получится переменная, где будут склеены все оставшиеся строки файла.